# Using Python & Pandas to turn flat list into matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I have an csv file that looks like:

```
A, 8.1, pass
B, 8.1, fail
A, 8.2, in-progress
B, 8.2, on-hold
C, 8.2, fail
...
F, 11.1, pass
```

That I want to turn into a file that looks like this:

```
Area   8.1   8.2   8.3   9.1   9.2.............11.1
A      Pass  In-Pr Fail  Pass  On-Hold         Pass
B      Fail  On-Ho Pass  Pass  Fail            Pass
C            Fail        Pass  On-Hold         Fail
...
F      Pass  Pass  On-H  Pass  Pass            Pass
```

Basically I'm looking for efficient template code that converts a flat listing into a matrix with an assigned value using pandas, preferably with a minimum of dataframes. I've tried using the converters={} option in pandas without success as this would do it upon the initial read.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) or [pivot()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for that:

```
In [253]: df.pivot_table(index='col1', columns='col2', values='col3', aggfunc='sum', fill_value='')
Out[253]:
col2  8.1          8.2   11.1
col1
A     pass  in-progress
B     fail      on-hold
C                  fail
F                        pass
```

or `pivot()`:

```
In [250]: df.pivot(index='col1', columns='col2', values='col3')
Out[250]:
col2  8.1          8.2   11.1
col1
A     pass  in-progress  None
B     fail      on-hold  None
C     None         fail  None
F     None         None  pass
```

DF:

```
In [251]: df
Out[251]:
  col1  col2         col3
0    A   8.1         pass
1    B   8.1         fail
2    A   8.2  in-progress
3    B   8.2      on-hold
4    C   8.2         fail
5    F  11.1         pass
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Setup

```
text = """A, 8.1, pass
B, 8.1, fail
A, 8.2, in-progress
B, 8.2, on-hold
C, 8.2, fail
F, 11.1, pass"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), names=['Area', 'col1', 'col2'])
```

#### Solution

Use `set_index` and `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['Area', 'col1']).unstack()
```

Looks like:

```
       col2                     
col1   8.1           8.2    11.1
Area                            
A      pass   in-progress   None
B      fail       on-hold   None
C      None          fail   None
F      None          None   pass
```

To get exactly what you posted as your output:

```
df.set_index(['Area', 'col1']).unstack().col2.rename_axis(None, axis=1).fillna('')
```

`.col2` grabs the first level column index with value `'col2'` getting rid of it in the displayed output.  `rename_axis` applies `None` to the name of the column index, getting rid of the displayed `col1` in the output.  `fillna('')` gets rid of the `None` values in the displayed output.
Looks like:

```
       8.1           8.2    11.1
Area                            
A      pass   in-progress       
B      fail       on-hold       
C                    fail       
F                           pass
```